# Setting variable with gdef does not work

Tags: macros, amsmath

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
%Define variable
\gdef\@depRe{chapter}
\def\depRe#1{\gdef\@depRe{#1}}

%Usie variable
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\@depRe]
\makeatother

%Set variable
\depRe{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Network}
\section{Cellular}
\begin{theorem}
This is an example.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, I defined 'depRe' variable and use it as theorem counter. But it does not worked for me and the value of 'depRe' (i.e. section) does not applied! Now put `\depRe{section}` before `\newtheorem ...`, so it works. Does any solution exist, which I can set 'depRe' after `\newtheorem` command?

It is worth noting that I have TexLive 2019.

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: For example suppose I am going to prepare a Latex style for report, article and etc. I defined `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\@depRe]` in one tex file named as env.tex. Then several files (e.g. myreport.tex, myarticle.tex) input the mentioned file (env.tex) and set appropriate `\depRe` parameter (e.g. chapter, section)

Comment: The trailing optional argument to `\newtheorem` should contain a counter name, which is *permanently* attached to the definition. When processing your `\newtheorem` declaration, `\@depRe` gets expanded to `chapter` and no trace of it remains in the definition of `theorem`.

Comment: The simplest fix would be to create two different theorem environments which use different counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\newtheorem`'s numbered-within-argument (which denotes the name of a counter) is fully evaluated at the time of carrying out `\newtheoremn`.

You can implement your environment using a fake-counter for `\newtheorem`'s numbered-within-argument and have a preamble-macro `\depRe` for redefining which real counter the fake-counter points to:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter

% define fake-infrastructure of fake-counter:
\newcommand*\c@MyFakeCnt{}%
\newcommand*\cl@MyFakeCnt{}%
\newcommand*\p@MyFakeCnt{}%
\newcommand*\theMyFakeCnt{}%
\newcommand*\theHMyFakeCnt{}%
\newcommand*\MyFakeCntautorefname{}%
\newcommand*\MyFakeCntname{}%

% define \depRe to map MyFakeCnt to counter denoted by argument:
\newcommand\depRe[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\c@MyFakeCnt\expandafter=\csname c@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\cl@MyFakeCnt\expandafter=\csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\p@MyFakeCnt\expandafter=\csname p@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\theMyFakeCnt\expandafter=\csname the#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\theHMyFakeCnt\expandafter=\csname theH#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\MyFakeCntautorefname\expandafter=\csname #1autorefname\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\MyFakeCntname\expandafter=\csname #1name\endcsname
}%
\@onlypreamble\depRe
% some initialization:
\depRe{section}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[MyFakeCnt]%

%\depRe{chapter}
\depRe{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Network}
\section{Cellular}
\begin{theorem}
This is an example.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When `\newtheorem` is processed, the trailing optional argument is expected to expand to a counter name; this counter is permanently attached to the environment's definition.

Technically speaking, the trailing argument is processed via `\csname...\endcsname`, which implies full expansion of the tokens in between.

If you want to make a package, I suggest using an option.

#### `diyanat.sty`

```latex
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=diyanat,
  prefix=diyanat@,
}

\DeclareStringOption[chapter]{theoremdepth}[chapter]
\define@key{diyanat}{theoremdepth}{\renewcommand{\diyanat@theoremdepth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\theoremdepth}{\diyanat@theoremdepth} % the user level interface

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
```

#### `test.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage{diyanat} % would use chapter
\usepackage[theoremdepth=section]{diyanat} % would use section

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\theoremdepth]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Network}

\section{Cellular}

\begin{theorem}
This is an example.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

#### Output with `\usepackage{diyanat}` or `\usepackage[theoremdepth=chapter]{diyanat}`

[image]

#### Output with `\usepackage[theoremdepth=section]{diyanat}`

[image]

Comment: such a nice suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments to your question I wonder whether you might be interested in nesting calls to `\@ifclassloaded`:

```
%\documentclass{book}
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\makeatletter
%%
%%\@ifclassloaded{<someclass>}{<true code>}{<false coode>}%
%%
\@ifclassloaded{book}{%
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]%
}{%
  \@ifclassloaded{report}{%
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]%
  }{%
    \@ifclassloaded{article}{%
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]%
    }{%
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{chapter}{\section}{\chapter}{Network}
\begin{theorem}
This is an example in a chapter.
\end{theorem}
\section{Cellular}
\begin{theorem}
This is an example in a section.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, but some one may be set section or chapter for report style.